# What does array do in this code?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am studying on udemy. I was writing the code of XOX game. I think all of us know XOX game. My code is working but i didn't understand what does this code do ?

```
for (int [] winningPosition : winningPositions){
                    if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                            gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2)}
```

The code which is the i dont get is above. Please help me with understand that.

```
{ package com.example.anild.xox;
    
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.GridLayout;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        // 0 = yellow, 1 = red
    
        int activePlayer = 0;
    
        boolean gameIsActive = true;
    
        //2 means unplayed
        int [] gameState = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
    
        int [][] winningPositions = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
    
        public void dropIn(View view) {
    
            ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;
    
            int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());
    
            if(gameState[tappedCounter] == 2 && gameIsActive) {
    
                //burada tappedCounterdaki sayıyı çekiyor yani tag'i daha sonra gamstate[] dizisine atıyor. Ve zaten hepsi 2 if koşulu sağlanıyor
                //Bir asağısında bu kural değişiyor. Bu alınan tag gametate'te artık 0 olarak saklanıyor :)
    
                gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;
    
                counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);
    
    
                if (activePlayer == 0) {
                    counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);
                    activePlayer = 1;
                } else {
                    counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
                    activePlayer = 0;
                }
    
                counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(360).setDuration(300);
    
                for (int [] winningPosition : winningPositions){
                    if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] && gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
                            gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2){
    
                        //someone has won
    
                        gameIsActive = false;
                        String winner = "Red";
                        if(gameState[winningPosition[0]] == 0){
                            winner = "Yellow";
    
                        }
    
                        TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
    
                        winnerMessage.setText(winner + "has won !");
    
                        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
    
    
                        layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    else {
                        boolean gameIsOver = true;
                        for(int counterState : gameState) {
                            if (counterState == 2) {
                                gameIsOver = false;
    
                            }
    
                            if (gameIsOver) {
                                TextView winnerMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerMessage);
    
                                winnerMessage.setText("it's a draw");
    
                                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
    
    
                                layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
    
    
        }
    
        public void playAgain(View view) {
    
            gameIsActive = true;
    
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
            layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    
            // 0 = yellow, 1 = red
    
            activePlayer = 0;
    
    
    
            for(int i = 0; i < gameState.length; i++) {
    
                gameState[i] = 2;
            }
    
            GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
    
            for(int i = 0; i < gridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
    
                ((ImageView) gridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(0);
    
            }
        }
    
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
    
    
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: THe array is hard coded.  You can see the values.  Its a really weird implementation but it works.  ALso, it isn't called the XOX game and I had no idea what you meant until I read the code-  its called tic-tac-toe.

Comment: 8 ways to win- 3 horizontal, 3 vertical, 2 diagonal. The days are the positions in the grid. Starting from square 0 to square 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering based on the question posed below my comment:

At it's most fundamental, the format for that for loop is

```
for('one object' : 'group of objects')
```

Now then, under ordinary circumstances you'd use something along the lines of:

```
for(String oneString : arrayOfStrings)
```

Based on your question, it appears as if you are unaware that you can statically specify an array of values by putting them inside braces.  For example:

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = {"zero", "one", "two"};
```

That produces exactly the same result as:

```
String[] arrayOfStrings = new String[3];
arrayOfStrings[0] = "zero";
arrayOfStrings[1] = "one";
arrayOfStrings[2] = "two";
```

You could loop over that with `for(String string : arrayOfStrings)`...

Going back to your original code - they have embedded braces inside braces, which is how you declare a multi-dimensional array.  So the following:

```
int [][] winningPositions = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
```

Produces the same array as:

```
int[][] winningPositions = new int[8][3];
winningPositions[0][0] = 0;
winningPositions[0][1] = 1;
winningPositions[0][2] = 2;
...
winningPositions[7][0] = 2;
winningPositions[7][1] = 4;
winningPositions[7][2] = 6;
```

With me so far?

The full "winningPositions" variable is an object of type array, whose content is itself a sequence of arrays.  Okay, so now when you do your loop that you don't understand, this:

```
for (int [] winningPosition : winningPositions)
```

Each item in the array "winningPosition" is itself an array - as I just said - so the "one object" resolves to the inner array, which has 3 elements, while the outer has 8.

Does that help?

*On a side note: Code like that is either aimed at new programmers, or else is written by someone that doesn't understand OO programming.  It's worthwhile to understand how it works, it is not necessarily meant to be emulated.  Or at least by the time you know I'm wrong about that, you'll know why I'm wrong.*

Answer (score 0):

`for (int [] winningPosition : winningPositions)`

Iterates through the array called `winningPositions`. Each iteration has the variable called `winningPosition` which is an int array of length 3.

```
if (gameState[winningPosition[0]] == gameState[winningPosition[1]] &&
    gameState[winningPosition[1]] == gameState[winningPosition[2]] &&
    gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2)
```

checks that all the positions are owned by the same player and the last part `gameState[winningPosition[0]] != 2` checks that the line isn't empty.

EDIT:

@ChrisParker explains this line very well in the comments. `for (int [] winningPosition : winningPositions)`

Comment: Good answer, but misses a salient point the OP may not know.  That type of 'for loop' is 'for(<one object> : <group of objects>)'.  Since the 'group of objects' is a two-dimensional array, the 'one object' resolves to a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @ChrisParker yes very true. That generalizes my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is iterating through the array and checking each of the conditions inside the if statement, IF all of them are true then the code will go inside the IF loop otherwise it will skip over and continue.

Cheers